# bash: using unzip to change filename within archive

Tags: linux, bash, zip, unzip

Given the following archive file20150101.zip, which contains only one file, file1115.txt, how would I go about renaming the file inside to match the name of the archive (file1115.txt to file20150101.txt)?

I've tried, unsuccessfully, to use unzip -u (most likely due to a misunderstanding of how it should work).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do this directly. You probably need to recreate the zip archive.

```
syncname() {
    zip=$1
    bare=${1%.zip}
    new=$bare.txt

    unzip "$zip"
    mv file*.txt "$new"
    rm "$zip"
    zip "$zip" "$new"
}

syncname file20150101.zip
```

If you wanted to be more robust, handle zips with multiple files, etc. you could work on parsing the date stamp in the original name (with `date`) and finding the matching `.txt` file for that stamp.